# Why doesn't Renderscript code update unless I uninstall my app between every change in my .rs files?

Tags: android, renderscript, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am running the Android M preview on my Nexus 6, but I doubt that's the issue.

Cleaning and rebuilding in Android Studio has no effect.

Comment: Try checking logcat during the time you do the launch/install. See if a new version of your APK was created and installed or if it says no install was needed and it is just launching the existing install.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer That's a good idea. I've been looking for the last ten minutes and I'm overwhelmed by all the verbose messages. Do you know any specific things I can search for to find either log entry?

Comment: I believe the M preview might be the issue because I never had such problem before. And yes I remember seeing some message during installation saying that it doesn't need to reprocess them. You should check for them.

Comment: @TimTrueman I forget the exact logcat entry, but it'll likely be from either PackageManager or installd indicating that no install is necessary, just activating the main `Activity` for the app.  Android Studio's output will also indicate that no new install is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I know this is an ancient question, but either way: clear the app cache, and you'll see the changes.

RenderScript compiled code exists in the app cache, in order to avoid compilation overhead on re-running (it's compiled once in Android Studio to intermediate bytecode, and then again on the device to device-specific machine code). See details here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJwKXOLjEPA, and here http://llvm.org/devmtg/2011-11/Hines_AndroidRenderscript.pdf .

If you want, you can do it in the app itself, at least while developing.